# Clone and analyze all (or as many as possible) github java projects

Tags: java, github, neo4j, abstract-syntax-tree, github-api

I want to somehow

1. get as many github java projects as possible, parse their source code
2. extract the AST with something like a [javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser),insert these ASTs in a NoSQL database (probably neo4j), and ask various kinds of static code analysis queries.

More info about part 2 here:

- [Graphlr: indexing antlr3 generated Java AST through a Neo4j
  graph](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/graphlr-indexing-antlr3-generated-java-ast-through-a-neo4j-graph/)
- [Expressive and Scalable Source Code Queries with Graph
  Databases](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kiss/14kor/oopsla13.pdf)

I have some trouble regarding the part 1 of this project.

I m thinking of using github api and do the following:

1. Write a script that gets as many github users as possible
2. For each user, get all repos with language=java, and clone them in a ramdisk directory (to avoid disk I/O) and overcome the lack of space.
3. Parse every .java file

Is this feasible? Can you think of another way where i don't need to clone the repo (e.g parse the "online" java source files)?

I don't need to parse all github repos at once. I ll have the neo4j node up and running, and I ll be able to add nodes (ASTs) on a reasonable time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 've carefully read the [github v3 api](https://developer.github.com/v3/) and managed to make progress.

First of all, I don't need

> 1. Write a script that gets as many github users as possible

as github v3 api provides a [url that lists all public repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-public-repositories).

I can then get the language of the repo via languages_url returned in the previous json object (something like https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo_name/languages), and keep the Java ones.

One thing to be noted, is [rate limiting](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting). Github allows 5,000 requests per hour for an authenticated user.

Considering the above, it should take some reasonable amount of time to patse (almost) every public java repo in Github.

Given that I need 2 api calls to fetch a repo's source code I can get 3000 java repos under a descent network connection in an hour. There are some millions public java projects on github.

I suppose I would some days to fetch them all.